# How to change the color of a pixel use Magick.NET?

Tags: c#, imagemagick

How to change pixel color on the image use the lib Magick.NET. I use the following code:

```
MagickImage img = new MagickImage(@"d:\TEST\110706M01000509.jpg");
WritablePixelCollection pc = img.GetWritablePixels(100, 100, 50, 50);

foreach (Pixel p in pc)
{
    p.SetChannel(0, 255);
    p.SetChannel(1, 0);
    p.SetChannel(2, 0);
}

pc.Write();

img.Write(@"d:\TEST\110706M01000509_.jpg");
```

But on the output image the color of the pixels no red.

Example:

[image]

Why the color of figures is not red?

Answer (score 3):

In 7.4, the above answers are largely correct, but, the method for getting the pixels is now

`magick.GetPixels()`

not

`magick.GetWritablePixels()`

They return `IPixelCollection`

Answer (score 1):

With the current version of Magick.NET (7.0.0.0014) you will need to do this:

```
using (WritablePixelCollection pc = img.GetWritablePixels(100, 100, 50, 50))
{
  foreach (Pixel p in pc)
  {
    p.SetChannel(0, 255);
    p.SetChannel(1, 0);
    p.SetChannel(2, 0);
    pc.Set(p) // This will update the PixelCollection
  }
}
```

With Magick.NET **7.0.0.0015** the call to *pc.Set* will be done automatically and your example above will work.

Answer (score -4):

in System.Drawing.Color "R", "G", and "B" are exist
just you should set your pixels to

```
Color.FromArgb(r,g,b);
```

it must be something to set pixels in that library, find it and do as what i said
Best Regards

Comment: this doesn't help him at all with imagemagick or with setting colors to individual  channels